# List of Dictionary is keeping only the last row

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

I have below code which adds `Dictionary` data to `List` of IDictionary as shown below

```
var datalist = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();

var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    foreach (var name in arrColumnNames)
    {
        data[name] = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[i][name]);
    }

    datalist.Add(data);
}
```

Now, issue is that my `datalist` keeps on updating last `data` values in entire List of `datalist`. What's wrong? How to keep `data` values preserved in `datalist`?

Comment: Why are you putting a dictionary within a list? What is it that you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: @AzzamAziz I updated the List as `  public static List<object> datalist = new List<object>();`, still its not preserving the Values. What's wrong here? I just want to preserve my format of data with above code

Comment: Thank you for that information. You might want to edit the code above so that other readers are able to see how it's changed too. It'll give me a better idea of what the new code is doing, and how to diagnose it.

Comment: You are creating only a single instace of a Dictionary and mutating it inside the loop, that's why you only get the last data values.

Comment: While I understand the reason it fails, I don't understand why don't you use DataTable class and I see no reason to write this code (in your question) at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [Spidey Senses](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Spidey%20sense) tells me you are new'ing this up for every method call, In short, the problem seems like you are creating a new list every time. However i could be completely wrong

Try this in your class, and remove it from the method

**Class field**

```
private List<IDictionary<string, string>> datalist = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();
```

**Method body**

Assuming your `arrColumnNames` is an instantiated List of string

You could do this with *Linq*

```
 var dict = dataTable.Rows
                     .Cast<DataColumnCollection>()
                     .Select(row => arrColumnNames.ToDictionary(x => x, x => row[x].ToString()))
                     .ToList();

 datalist.AddRange(dict);
```

***Footnote*** : i think this is all a little-bit suspect. Are you sure you want a `Dictionary` in a `List`, and not a `Dictionary` of `Key` and `List`

Comment: Applied the suggestion but unfortunately, its still the same, just preserving the last row data!! What can be issue now?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is get a shallow copy of the dictionary after you add the data to the list, try this

```
var datalist = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();

var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    foreach (var name in arrColumnNames)
    {
        data[name] = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[i][name]);
    }

    datalist.Add(data);
    data = new Dictionary<string, string>(data);
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this line will fail with KeyNotFound exception or something like that: data[name] = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[i][name]);

Answer (score 0):

```
var datalist = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();
for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
  var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var name in arrColumnNames)
    { 
      data[name] = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[i][name]);
    }
    datalist.Add(data);
}
```

Moved Dictionary Declaration inside for loop ,so that each data table it creates new object of dictionary and add all the Columns. Otherwise Dictionary keeps last datable Column details

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

You are only creating a single instance of a Dictionary (outside the `for` loop), and adding the same instance of it for each row inside the loop.

As it stands, your list will end up being a list of references to the same dictionary, and since the final row in the table has the same columns as all the other rows, you end up with what would look like a list of dictionaries all with the values from the last row. But in fact it's a list where each entry points at the same dictionary, which only contains values from the last row because it has overwritten all the previous values.

If you move the line initializing `data` inside the for loop, you will end up with a list (one entry for each row) of dictionaries where the key is the column name and the value is the value for that column for that row.

Comment: @RAM your code was only one line-move away from working, as I had described above. TheGeneral's approach just does what you were doing in a different way; but if you don't understand what you did wrong, you're going to have similar problems in future again and again. Please try my solution, so you can understand what was wrong.

Answer (score -2):

You have to move

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Into

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; ++i)
```

Before the `foreach` loop.